# Make element fill rest of div without resizing Image

Tags: html, css, image, width

I want the Logo Image in this nav-bar to fill its height while still retaining its aspect ratio. The remaining width should be filled by the ul element.
As long as the ul elements width is not 100% the image is displayed correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/5o0b4xLd/

How can I do that?

The Code:

```
<div id="navbar">
<div id="logoBox">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wuRN2wD.png" id="logo">
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#fakelink">
            Item 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#fakelink">
            Item 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#fakelink">
            Item 3
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#fakelink">
            Item 4
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#fakelink">
            Item 5
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
#navbar {
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    height: 3.8em;
    margin-top: 4em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #f39c12;
}

#logoBox {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#logo {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#navbar ul {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 1.9em;
    line-height: 0;
}

#navbar a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an illustration with desired result?

Comment: It should look like [this](http://puu.sh/isafo.png). Even though the spacing on the menu Items is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current issue is in the `#logo` attributes - `max-width` and `max-height` won't actually expand the div unless there is content inside that forces it to expand.  Also, you'll want to set the `background-size = cover` so the aspect ratio is maintained.

Try this instead:

`#logo {
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: With these edits the Image is just stretched out to the bottom and the aspect ratio is lost.

Comment: Make sure you remove the `max-width` attribute from `#logo` and add `width: 100%;` to `#logobox`.  I've got a working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vLk4xw8o/

Comment: Now the Navigation bar glitches into the image.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that shortly after posting and edited my comment - take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/vLk4xw8o again

Comment: I already tried that too but now the menu is somehow centered. Its weird that the div does not have the same size as the Image in it even though its set to `display: inline-block`

Comment: Yeah - that has something to do with the widths being calculated improperly on `#logobox` and `#navbar ul` - change the widths on both of those to auto instead of 100% and remove the overflow attribute from `#navbar ul` so all the menu items are shown: http://jsfiddle.net/vLk4xw8o/2/

Answer (score 0):

here edit your css like following:
i added background image & background size to scale image via width. Also hiding the actual image to make it just a placeholder, rest of code is fine.

```
#logoBox {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/wuRN2wD.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

#logo {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: With these edits the Image is stretched out to the bottom while the aspect ratio is lost.

Comment: aspect ratio is not lost, its just that image's extra width is hidden. you have to sacrifice that much, otherwise you can do presice calculations for pixels size of logo, its navbar etc to completely fit the image.